# How do I make Firefox 64 use the KDE file selection dialog?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, kde, gtk3

By default, Firefox uses the GTK file selection dialog when you press, for example, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open a local file.

How does a Kubuntu user make Firefox use the KDE file selection dialog?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit**: this question deals with Kubuntu 18.04. Users of Kubuntu 20.04 will find the experience very decent.

---

This is possible in Firefox 64 with the important caveat that it is **currently buggy**. See the edit below.

First, Kubuntu 18.04+ users need to install `xdg-desktop-portal`. Your system probably already has `xdg-desktop-portal-kde` installed by default.

- To see if you like it, simply run `GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 firefox`
- If you want to keep the KDE file selection dialog for Firefox, add `export GTK_USE_PORTAL=1` to the end of your `~/.profile` assuming your system doesn't use either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`. Neither `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bash_login` are present in a default Kubuntu installation. Log out and log back in.

This is an image of the GTK file selection dialog in Firefox 64:

[image: GTK file selection dialog]

And this is what the KDE file selection dialog looks like in Firefox 64:

[image: Firefox 64 with KDE file selection dialog]

This way, other programs like Thunderbird will also use KDE dialogs.

Sources:

- [Firefox v64 can now use the KDE file selection dialog when run with GTK_USE_PORTAL=1](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a5cxwk/firefox_v64_can_now_use_the_kde_file_selection/)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/a59ip5/firefox_640_released/eblfwcb
- https://pointieststick.wordpress.com/2018/12/16/this-week-in-usability-productivity-part-49/

---

**Edit** (thanks to the comments provided by [cipricus](https://askubuntu.com/users/47206/cipricus)):

- There is currently a major issue with the "Save As ..." aspect. Users need provide the filename and the extension themselves. This can be difficult when one is downloading, for example, a `.deb` file from https://www.google.com/chrome/. [Bug 402077 - SaveFile does not set the current_name](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=402077) may have addressed this issue to some extent.
- Other usability issues relate to the file selection dialog defaulting to the root folder if a user sets Firefox to ask for the download destination.

Comment: is the problem with the need to untick `Automatically select filename extension ...` rather severe? should it be un-ticked every time? Are there some limitations with the default gtk interface? is thus Firefox displaying kde instead of gtk allover after that?

Comment: When I try to save a file, Kubuntu 18.04: **(A)** if in Preferences I have selected "Always ask you where to save" **(1A)** root location is selected by default, so that I have to change the location,  **(2B)** when saving a file the window is not `Save as`, but `Enter name of file to save to...`  so that I have to enter the full name not just the extension; **(B)**, if in Preferences "Save files to: Downloads" is selected, the file is saved automatically with its own name without problems (but without seeing the kde interface).

Comment: `provide the filename extension themselves` - that is: write it, not just select it from a list: do I really have to know extensions in order to download a file?  I am supposed to know its extension before even downloading it:  I find that a severe problem.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I'm concerned the bugs make it unusable because I don't see the kde dialog in other cases but the ones in which it is broken, namely "save as" (as automatic saving doesn't trigger kde interface at all). I imagine "open file" would be another case (and that should work), but I never use that.

Comment: I was interested in using this solution if it worked, but the gtk default is fine for me. I will not spend time on this now, especially that I'm not the man for bug reports at all and risk to give dubious info. I'll wait for the kde integration to become default.

Comment: Fair enough! I'll keep watching for developments.

Comment: This works with Firefox. Does not work with some GTK Applications, such as Darktable. Is there another fix?

Comment: #402077 is fixed at least in 20.04

Comment: What about **chromium**?

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me after I added that variable to `~/.zshenv`

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions of Firefox, you can go to `about:config` and set `widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal` to `true`. It's much easier than setting the `GTK_USE_PORTAL=1` environment varibable in the Firefox launcher.

Comment: Very nice! It works immediately without restarting browser (tested it with `Ctrl+O` - open file - dialog).

Comment: Note: Other answers are useful if someone wants a way to make several programs (Firefox, Thunderbird, etc.) use KDE dialogs.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a recent change, but I find with current firefox there is not a setting named widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal but rather several settings starting with that including widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Firefox) and setting that one to 1 (it might be 0 or 2) is what you need now.