# Kubuntu 20.04 - Change or edit the default file picker

Tags: kubuntu

I have problem with the default file picker GtkFileChooser and the detail view in it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZLlX.png (similar GTK)

How do I change the view mode from detail view to icon view?

Optionally, how do I change GtkFileChooser to KDE file selector?

The detail view is very frustrating when picking the image from large image folder.

Chromium and Firefox open GtkFileChooser by default, Kate opens KDE file selector. It would be good if browsers open KDE file selctor too.

Comment: **1**: that image is of a **gtk** file chooser. I'm not sure icon view is an option here. **2**Kate doesn't open Dolphin. It uses the KDE file chooser, which is customizable. You have the icon view available there. But see https://askubuntu.com/a/1100284/248158 to learn how to make Firefox and other applications use the (better) KDE file chooser.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, just edited the correct names. I'll check the firefox solution.