# How to Use KDE / Plasma Dialogs in Thunderbird

Tags: kde, thunderbird, plasma, dialog

While getting Firefox to use KDE / Plasma dialogs was not straightforward, following [this link](https://userbase.kde.org/Browser_Configuration/Firefox_Dialog_Integration) and rebooting my machine got it working.

Thunderbird seems to be another kind of animal, though.

Copying the thunderbird.desktop file to my home directory does not help. Editing the menu entry to look like `GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 thunderbird` does not help.

I am able to get the plasma dialogs by running the above command from terminal, which then throws lots of errors:

```
~$ GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 thunderbird
[calBackendLoader] Using Thunderbird's libical backend
console.debug: "Successfully loaded OpenPGP library librnp.so from /usr/lib/thunderbird/librnp.so"
Extension error: Error while loading 'jar:file:///usr/lib/thunderbird/omni.ja!/chrome/messenger/search-extensions/twitter/manifest.json' (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:570 :: readJSON/</<@resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:570:20
onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:128:18

console.debug: "public keys: 0, secret keys: 0"
console.debug: "Successfully loaded optional OpenPGP library libgpgme.so.11 from system's standard library locations"
console.debug: "gpgme version: 1.13.1-unknown"
console.log: (new Error("Cannot load required OTR library", "resource:///modules/OTRLib.jsm", 75))
JavaScript error: chrome://chat/content/conversation-browser.js, line 853: NotSupportedError: CustomElementRegistry.define: 'conversation-browser' has already been defined as a custom element
JavaScript error: , line 0: uncaught exception: 2147500036
```

Thunderbird eventually opens, asking me to select system integration. Then it will use Plasma dialogs, but on next startup it will return to its default dialog.

So, how do I get Thunderbird to use KDE / Plasma file dialogs every time?

Comment: I am aware of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119489/how-to-use-kde-dialogs-in-gtk-apps). That answer is now outdated.

Answer (score 6):

Edit --> Preferences
then at the end click "Config Editor..:"
in the config editor search for xdg
toggle widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal to true

Comment: For me, in Thunderbird 115.6.1, there are a bunch of xdg-desktop-portal settings that I needed to change from `2` to `1` to enable the KDE native dialogs.